# Disable coupons & discounts from applying to defined Woocommerce products in cart

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I would like to stop any discount code being applied when purchasing a certain product (in this case a Gift Card). Other items in the cart should be unaffected and have the discount code applied to them.

I know that this can be done on the individual coupon creation page, but with hundreds of coupons already made I'd like a way for this to apply automatically.

All help is very appreciated!

This the closest code I have found, but it relates to a plugin rather than woocommerce in general.

```
add_filter('eha_dp_skip_product','skip_product_from_discount',1,4);
function skip_product_from_discount($return_val,$pid,$rule,$mode)
{
    $pid_to_skip=array(53189);    // specify pids to skip
    if($mode=='category_rules'  && in_array($pid,$pid_to_skip))
    {
        return true;  // true to skip this product
    }
    return $return_val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic simple & effective way to do that should be through **coupon settings restrictions**:

[image]

> **BUT as you have a lot of coupons** here is a custom function **to bulk update coupons "excluded product" restrictions**:

```
function bulk_edit_coupon_restrictions(){
    // Only for admin users (not accessible) for other users)
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) return;

    global $wpdb;

    // Set HERE the product IDs without discount
    $product_ids = array( 37, 67 );

    $product_ids = implode( ',', $product_ids );  // String conversion

    // SQL query: Bulk update coupons "excluded product" restrictions
    $wpdb->query( "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
        SET pm.meta_value = '$product_ids'
        WHERE pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_ids'
        AND post_id IN (
            SELECT p.ID
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
            WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        )
    " );
}
// Run this function once (and comment it or remove it)
bulk_edit_coupon_restrictions();
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

---

> **USAGE**
>
> 1) **Make a database backup** (or in particular the **`wp_postmeta`** table).
>   2) Set your product ID (or products IDs) in the array (without discount).
>   3) Paste that code in **`function.php`** file of your active theme **and save it**.
>   4) Under an admin account, **browse any page** of your web site.
>   5) Comment or remove that code.
>   6) You are done and **you can check some coupons** to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the above answer as the Yith Gift Cards Plugin team got back to me. For anyone looking for the answer relating directly to the Yith plugin, here's the code...

```
  if( defined('YITH_YWGC_PREMIUM') ){
 if( !function_exists('yith_wcgc_deny_coupon_on_gift_card') ){
  add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon','yith_wcgc_deny_coupon_on_gift_card');

  function yith_wcgc_deny_coupon_on_gift_card( $coupon_code ){
      global $woocommerce;
      $the_coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
      $excluded_items = $the_coupon->get_excluded_product_ids();
      $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
      foreach ( $items as $item ):
    if( has_term('gift-card','product_type',$item['product_id']) == true ):
        $excluded_items[] = $item['product_id'];
    endif;
      endforeach;
      $the_coupon->set_excluded_product_ids($excluded_items);
      $the_coupon->save();
      wc_add_notice( 'Coupon cannot applied to gift card product', 'error' );

  }
 }

}
```