# Exclude products with specific attributes terms from WooCommerce coupons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, taxonomy-terms

I would like to exclude from all WooCommerce coupons the products that have a specific attribute (e.g. attribute_pa_brand => mybrand).

I followed this answer [Exclude variations with 2 specific attribute terms from coupon usage in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297527/exclude-variations-with-2-specific-attribute-terms-from-coupon-usage-in-woocomme)  but it seems to apply only to the **Variable Product** type, while I would only need it for the **Simple Product**.

I will be grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [linked code from your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297527/exclude-variations-with-2-specific-attribute-terms-from-coupon-usage-in-woocomme/54310492#54310492) is for product variation type. Now to make it work for simple products and variable products *(without targeting specific variations attributes terms)*, you will use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'custom_coupon_validity', 10, 3 );
function custom_coupon_validity( $is_valid, $coupon, $discount ){
    // YOUR ATTRIBUTE SETTINGS BELOW:
    $taxonomy   = 'pa_brand'; // Set the taxonomy (start always with "pa_" + the slug)
    $term_names = array('Apple', 'Sony'); // Set your term NAMES to be excluded

    $term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Convert term names to term Ids
    foreach ( $term_names as $term_name ) {
        // Set each term id in the array
        $term_ids[] = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->term_id;
    }

    // Loop through cart items and check for backordered items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']) : $cart_item['data'];
        // Loop through product attributes
        foreach( $product->get_attributes() as $attribute => $values ) {
            if( $attribute === $taxonomy && array_intersect( $values->get_options(), $term_ids ) ) {
                $is_valid = false; // attribute found, coupons are not valid
                break; // Stop and exit from the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return $is_valid;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works for simple and variable products on last WooCommerce version.

Comment: Thanks Loic. I have hoped so much for your answer. It works perfectly. I hope to meet you again!